# Office-JS ignores trailing new-lines in Word for Mac

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

In my Office-JS Add-In I'm inserting a text with a trailing newline and set the cursor to the end of this text like this:

```
function myInsertTest() {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    var selectedRange = context.document.getSelection();
    selectedRange.insertText("myText", "End");
    selectedRange.insertText("\r\n", "End");
    selectedRange.select("End");
    return context.sync();
  });
}
```

In Word 2016 on Windows the cursor is correctly set to the second line, but in Word for Mac (Version 16.11) the cursor is set to the end of the first line.

So if I run this function for example 3 times in a row this results in the following texts:

**On Windows:**

```
myText
myText
myText
<-- Cursor is here
```

**On Mac:**

```
myTextmyTextmyText<-- Cursor is here
// 3 new lines following
```

---

Did I miss something?

Comment: Does anything change if you use "\n" instead of "\r\n"? Word uses only ANSI 13, not ANSI 10 + ANSI 13 for new *paragraphs*. (New *lines* are ANSI 11...) possibly MacWord doesn't like the ANSI 10.

Comment: Yes, I also tried with "\n". I also tried to use `selectedRange.insertBreak('line', 'After');`. "\n" behaves the same as "\r\n", while using the insertBreak function makes it even worse and causes the same misbehaviour on windows too.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. The Office Platform team has confirmed that this is a bug and it's being tracked internally for investigation & resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually a bug and in fact its now failing in the latest builds for Windows. Thanks for reporting this issue we will look into it and fix soon.

Comment: Hi Juan. We recently noticed that this bug is now also occurring in the latest version of O365 on Windows (Version 1803 Build 9126.2259 Click-to-Run).

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid dealing with new line oddities by allowing Word to handle this for you. The trick is to provide insert an HTML `<br>` tag using `insertHtml()` instead:

```js
function myInsertTest() {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    let selectedRange = context.document.getSelection();
    selectedRange.insertText("myText", "End");
    selectedRange.insertHtml("<br />&nbsp;", "End");
    selectedRange.select("End");
  });
}
```

Note that the `&nbsp;` is required to get around Word being a little too clever and ignoring a break that doesn't have any content after it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but adding a space at the beginning of every line is not very beautiful... can you imagine a way to get rid of that space again? Instead of the non breaking space I would actually need a non spacing space ;)
I already tried to delete the space by inserting \b after it, unfortunately \b did not work as expected.

Comment: I also just noticed that the insertHtml function behaves different in Word 2016 on Windows, there it seems like the HTML is inserted as a paragraph.

Comment: Interesting, this is _not_ what I'm seeing. I'm getting line break on Word 2016 for both Windows and Mac. I'm also not seeing a leading space.

Comment: It seems that there are some differences between versions. Since I have no Office 365 subscription, I have a quite old build (16.0.4639) on Windows. On mac there seem to be differences between Office for Mac and Word for Mac?

Comment: Office for Mac is a bundled package that includes Word for Mac, they are not different products. There are however substantial differences between the standalone Office and Office 365 due to the monthly updates that get rolled out with Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript

```
String.fromCharCode(13)
```

to insert ANSI 13 (the character Word uses). So:

```
function myInsertTest() {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    var selectedRange = context.document.getSelection();
    selectedRange.insertText("myText", "End");
    selectedRange.insertText(String.fromCharCode(13), "End");
    selectedRange.select("End");
    return context.sync();
  });
}
```

Comment: @ndreisg Above comment and... in what environment are you running your code? Script Lab? I had some issues with that in MacWord if I run the code from the "Run" screen - but it worked when running from the "Code" screen.

Comment: I am developing my Add-In on Windows. To test it on the Mac, I publish it to Azure. So I actually tested it in a productive environment.
Though there may be differences between Word versions.